# .NET Replacement Shell not retrieving file contents during startup

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, user-interface

I have an application I wrote that replaces Windows Explorer as a shell for Kiosk purposes.  The application maintains two configuration files: one that is used and maintained for application purpose (app.config) and another that is stored in another directory so it doesn't get overwritten when the GUI attempts to update from a repository.

When the application is ran in a normal environment it works perfectly.  However when it is used during start-up or when switching users, the application can't seem to load the information in the other directory.

**From the manager class**

```
Private Shared rootCP As String
Friend Shared Sub loadConfig()

    Dim dir As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory)

    Try
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(dir.Parent.FullName & "\local.config")
        rootCP = objReader.ReadToEnd
        objReader.Close()
    Catch Ex As Exception
        'DEBUG: console.write(ex.message)
    End Try

    dir = Nothing

End Sub
```

**From the MainForm_Load sub**

```
Manager.loadConfig()
```

Another function later attempts to retrieve the data from the rootCP string but can only access it if the application was started after system start-up. Any thoughts (VB.NET or C# is fine)?

Comment: What version of Windows and what folder are you storing the config file in.

Comment: Using Environment.CurrentDirectory as base for searching configuration files looks questionsable... Are you sure that the path you tring to read config file from is correct?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the application configuration at runtime?

Comment: The repository function works ok and the path is correct so no need to worry about that. The application works when called from explorer and works when manually replacing the shell. Only during start-up or switching users does it file fail to load. The OS is developed for WinXP Embedded 2007.

The path structure looks like this:

C:\applicationdir

C:\applicationdir\local.config <- the file that is not loading

C:\applicationdir\versiondir

C:\applicationdir\versiondir\app.exe

C:\applicationdir\versiondir\app.config <- This changes with repository updates which is the reason for two configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these might work for you.  I almost always use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`.  Don't use `CodeBase` on the assembly, it can be something you might not expect.

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

For windows apps:

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```

Because the normal ways aren't working, it's hard for me to say which of these will for sure.  Also, always use `Path.Combine(...)` to pull two paths together.

Comment: Replacing Environment.CurrentDirectory with AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory worked.  Much appreciated!